# Adjusting object keys after deleting key

Tags: javascript, arrays

In Javascript, I have an array of objects like so:

```
var array = [{ foo: 'bar' }, { foo: 'baz' }, { foo: 'qux' }];
```

which looks like this, really...

```
[0: {...}, 1: {...}, 2: {...}]
```

and I delete the second one:

```
delete array[1];
```

then I have this:

```
[0: {...}, 2: {...}]
```

How can I adjust this array so the keys are back in numerical order?

Comment: ^ If you don't use `delete`, you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is what you are looking for in this case

```
array.splice(1,1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method instead:

```
array.splice(1, 1);
```

Will remove 1 object at index 1, without leaving an empty space.